# android mediaplayer loops forever on ICS

Tags: android, loops, notifications, media-player

I want to play a notification sound and my problem it that the sound loops forever, when it should sound only once.

I've tried two ways:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/38");
```

and

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/38"));
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.v(Utils.TAG, "onprepared");
        mp.start();
    }
});

mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.v(Utils.TAG, "end, we should release");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
});
```

In the second case, I never see the trace "end, we should release", the audio is played over and over and over again.

Any idea?

Thank you very much

**UPDATE:**

I've tried two devices and:

- It loops forever on a Galaxy Nexus with ICS 4.0.4
- It works fine on a HTC Hero 2.2.1

Comment: what device are you testing on?

Comment: Hi Tim, I've updated my question. It seems that it doesn't work fine on the ICS

Comment: Zegnus, did you ever solve the problem? I confirm that I am seeing the same issue on my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 7):

There are sounds with "built-in" loops which will play for ever. This is different to setting the MediaPlayer to looping. If you start playing a sound with a built-in loop, it will never finish. These are mostly ring tones (as opposed to alarm tones or notification tones). You can set the RingtoneManager to return only notification tones or alarm tones with `myringtonemanager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM|RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`
which will exclude most looping sounds, but unfortunaley this is not guaranteed to exclude them all on any device. **:-(**

Therefore the solution of Tiago Almeida is a good work-around (and i've voted it up) though it will also truncate all sounds which have just a few (and no infinite) loops.

Comment: The `setOnSeekCompleteListener` workaround does not work for me. Is there any other solution for this issues or I should use my own sounds to be sure?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
try {
    mp.setDataSource(uri.toString());
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: In my case the `setOnSeekCompleteListener` is not called for sounds with infinite loops so they loop forever. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @shelll Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @morha13 I am sorry but no.

Answer (score 0):

One more workaround for this problem

```
boolean soundPlayedOnce = true;

if(soundPlayedOnce){
   mp.start();
   soundPlayedOnce = false;
}
```

set this boolean to true right before you want to play sound