# Playing sound only once

Tags: android, audio, notifications, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an alarm sound exactly once:

```
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

    final MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, notification);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

But the sound plays endlessly, although 'setLooping' is set to false.
What else can I do to make the sound not loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call:

```
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Is a blocking call for files so you dont really need the listener, you can just call:

```
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Right after it.
Also it start from time 0 so you dont need:

```
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
```

As to the endless playing, you can find the explanation and solution here:

[android mediaplayer loops forever on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770752/android-mediaplayer-loops-forever-on-ics)